# Decrypting password with sha512_crypt - python3

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, sha512

I am implementing a basic web scraping webapp that requires registration and login to use the features. I am now facing an issue in the login [see below the code, please] when trying to decrypt a pwd from the mongodb database. I cannot pass the correct value in the sha512_crypt function, resulting in errors such as: '''ValueError: not a valid sha512_crypt hash'''

I have extensively researched the problem and tried multiple things, but still issues: What can you suggest? Thanks

```
#route for the signin  page
@app.route("/signin", methods = ['GET', "POST"]) 
def signin():
    form = Signin(request.form)
    if request.method == 'GET': # make sure the method used is define above
    return render_template('signin.html', form = form), print("you are under the signin page now, well done mrbacco")
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    # the following are the data from the init form
    email = form.email.data
    password_form = form.password.data
        print("these are the email and password inserted", email, password_form)

    user_db = mycol_u.find_one({'email' : email})
    for key, value in user_db.items():
        print ("these are the fields in the db ", key, value)

    if user_db is None:
        flash("No USER FOUND!!, please try again", "danger")
        return render_template('signin.html', form = form), print("user not found, flashed a message on the web page")

    if sha512_crypt.verify(user_db['password'], password_form):
        flash("You are now logged in", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("home.html",form = form))
    else:
        flash("credential not correct, please try again", "danger")

    print("redirecting to scraping page")
return render_template('signin.html', form = form)
```

Comment: Check the definition of the `verify` function, I'm pretty sure the unencrypted password should be the first argument.

Comment: that works, you were right, @Joe ... thanks I checked everything but not the easiest thing ...